# How to generate an unique code for every node

Tags: 6, entities, hooks

I have a social article website; I created a content type named Article.
When a user creates an article, I want to generate a code shown to the user. This code should be saved in the database because users can return to this article with this code.
It's important to build a views with this code.

I think I must create a CCK field, generate a code (for example hash the node ID or the timestamp of when the node has been create), and show this code in disable a text box for the  author.

Is there any module to do this? What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some PHP knowledge, you can implemented the field using the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module. You can also use the module [Universally Unique IDentifier](http://drupal.org/project/uuid). This does not require PHP knowledge, but does not store the code as a CCK field.

Comment: Thanks,I use Computed Field and set Time() for unique field.